# How do I use "projectVersionPolicyId" in Maven Release Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

There is a parameter `projectVersionPolicyId` in many mojos of Maven Release Plugin, e.g. http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#projectVersionPolicyId. However, it seems that they provided no examples of how I can use it.

When I try:

```
$ mvn --batch-mode release:prepare -DprojectVersionPolicyId=foo
```

It shows an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project maven-release-test: Policy 'foo' is unknown, available: [default] -> [Help 1]
```

It looks like that there only 1 available policy (which is `default`). Is there any way to add more possible policies?

Comment: Hi! Have you since figured out a way to use your custom policy?

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SemVerVersionPolicy` as well